# Get Property As Integer throws Runtime Error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I wrote a class module called TimeManagementTable to abstract out some data for a table that I'm working with. Here's that code:

```
Option Explicit
Private table As ListObject
Private idColumn As Integer
Private subColumn As Integer
Private descColumn As Integer
Private epColumn As Integer

' ERROR -1: No Table
' ERROR -2: Columns Not Found
Public Function init(newSelection As Range) As Variant
    Dim column As ListColumn
    Dim msg As Variant

    If newSelection.ListObject Is Nothing Then
        msg = MsgBox("Table not detected!", vbCritical, "Aborted")
        init = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set table = newSelection.ListObject
    For Each column In table.ListColumns
        Select Case column.Name
            Case "ID"
                idColumn = Int(column.Index)
            Case "SUB"
                subColumn = Int(column.Index)
            Case "Description"
                descColumn = Int(column.Index)
            Case "EP"
                epColumn = Int(column.Index)
        End Select
        If (idColumn > 0 And subColumn > 0 And descColumn > 0 And epColumn > 0) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If (idColumn = 0 Or subColumn = 0 Or descColumn = 0 Or epColumn = 0) Then
        msg = MsgBox("Either EP, ID, SUB, or Description column not detected!", vbCritical, "Aborted")
        init = -2
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function

Public Property Get TableObject() As ListObject
    Set TableObject = table
End Property

Public Property Get IDColumnInde() As Integer
    IDColumnInde = idColumn
End Property

Public Property Get SUBColumnInde() As Integer
    SUBColumnInde = subColumn
End Property

Public Property Get DescColumnInde() As Integer
    DescColumnInde = descColumn
End Property

Public Property Get EPColumnInde() As Integer
    EPColumnInde = epColumn
End Property
```

I have a call to the first Get property that looks like this:

```
Set newSelection = Application.InputBox("Please enter which Time Log table you would like to add a row to:", "Insert New Entry", "DeliverableTimeLog", , , , , 8)
Set tmt = New TimeManagementTable
If (tmt.init(newSelection) < 0) Then Exit Sub
For Each row In tmt.TableObject.ListRows
   if row.Range.Formula(1, tmt.IDColumnIndex) = choiceID
```

Where tmt is an object of TimeManagementTable, row is a ListRow object, and choiceID is an integer.

Every Time I run the macro with the for each loop now I get

> Runtime Error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get
>   procedure did not return an object

at the end of this Get Property:

```
Public Property Get IDColumnIndex() As Integer
    IDColumnIndex = idColumn
End Property
```

I feel like I'm losing my mind all it's doing is returning an integer. If anyone can help me understand what is going on that would be amazing. If you need more info let me know I tried to keep this as concise as possible.

EDIT: full class module source and initialization

Comment: Sorry, it's Index. It's all the same in the code that's one of the things I tried because I thought maybe it didn't like that I had index in the identifier. Stupid I know but this was about 3 hours into trying to figure it out lol

Comment: If you put `Option Explicit` at the top of your class module, does it compile? Is this the whole class' listing?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It does compile and run and throws the same error.

Comment: What's `tmt`? How's that set?

Comment: But you aren't showing us your actual class module (the encapsulated values can't be assigned). The error you're getting indicates a typo or something like it. Don't give us a screenshot of the code, I can't paste a screenshot into the VBE.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the error and the full source of the class module, there's an init function in there as well to initialize the properties.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. I'll post the whole source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is basically saying that you're trying to assign to a `Property Get` member.

```
SomeGetter = 42
```

That's illegal, because you can't assign to a property that doesn't have a `Property Let` accessor.

The part about "doesn't return an object" is because this:

```
SomeGetter = 42
```

*Would* be legal, if `SomeGetter` returned an object with a default member that's assignable to the RHS value. In other words because VBA can't see this:

```
SomeGetter.DefaultProperty = 42
```

Then it throws an error, because `SomeGetter` can't be LHS of an assignment. Look for a typo. Make sure every module says `Option Explicit` at the top, particularly the class module and the module with the loop that's throwing the error.

Your post looks like it contains multiple mixed versions of the code, making it hard to tell exactly where the problem is.

---

Actually...

```
if row.Range.Formula(1, tmt.IDColumnIndex) = choiceID
```

Formula is a `Variant` property, but I've never seen it indexed like this. I think *that* is the property VBA is complaining about. Did you mean to do this?

```
if row.Range.Cells(1, tmt.IDColumnIndex).Value = choiceID
```

Comment: The getter or the return value of the getter is never in contact with the equality operator, the return value of "row.Range.Formula(int, int)" is. It's within the bounds of an if statement as well so it would be an equality operator and not an assignment operator right?

Comment: Correct. Isn't the VBE selecting the faulty statement when it throws the error though?

Comment: Wait how is `Range.Formula(int,int)` supposed to work? I've only ever seen `Range.Formula` assigned/compared to a string... you're comparing to some value, did you mean to compare `.Value`? I think `Formula(int,int)` compiles only because it's a `Variant` and thus gets evaluated at run-time. The comparison is illegal, and the typos and getters were a red herring.

Comment: Yup that last part was it. Sorry, I'm learning as I go with VBA and using .Formula worked for me before. I replaced it with row.Range.Cells(int,int).value and it worked. Thank you so much for your help!